# loading data into dataGridView from C structures

Tags: c#, datagridview, structure

I am trying to create a data visualizer in c# for an array of structures created in a C legacy app.  I believe that the best way to do this is to use a winforms dataGridView.  I am unable to find any examples here or on the Internet of doing such a thing.

Can anyone either point me to an example, or at least an example of where I might start?

Comment: Marshal the structs to C#. Create an `IList` or `IBindingList` from the structs. [Optional: Create a BindingSource from the list.] Set the DataGridView's `DataSource` property. For further help, you need to specify your problem more concise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are no examples on the internet to be found.  Sigh.